# Android - I need to create an always running service that monitors the users location

Tags: android, service, background, broadcast, receiver

I'm using [Radar](https://radar.io/) to monitor the users location. The thing is I need to keep tracking location after the app closes. I'm using a features called Geofences, it's basically just a location, and the goal is to send a notification whenever a user enters one.

This is my Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class RadarBroadcastReceiver extends RadarReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "RadarBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onEventsReceived(Context context, RadarEvent[] events, RadarUser user) {
    for (RadarEvent event : events){
        if (event.getType() == RadarEvent.RadarEventType.USER_ENTERED_GEOFENCE){
            Log.i(TAG, "onEventsReceived: User entered GeoFence ->" + event.getGeofence().getExternalId());
        }
        if (event.getType() == RadarEvent.RadarEventType.USER_EXITED_GEOFENCE){
            Log.i(TAG, "onEventsReceived: User exited GeoFence ->" + event.getGeofence().getExternalId());
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onEventsReceived: User did some other event");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationUpdated(Context context, Location location, RadarUser user) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationUpdated: User location updated");
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, Radar.RadarStatus status) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onError: an error occurred. Radar status -> "+status);
}
}
```

And added it to my manifest

```
<receiver
  android:name=".MyRadarBroadcastReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="io.radar.sdk.RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Now where do I go from here? To summarize everything, I need the BroadcastReceiver always running, and when I receive an event (like entering a geofence), I need to notify the user. I've read all the documentation I can find and it's still not very clear because my use case is a little different.

Thanks

Comment: The point of a GeoFence is that you don't need an always running Service. The Geofence pings you when you enter/exit a certain location and then your service fires up.

Comment: @Blundell Yes, so this works fine when the app is open, but if it's closed or killed, it doesn't seem to fire anything

Comment: Sorry I've not used that SDK, but its explained expliclty in the docs: https://radar.io/documentation/sdk#android-background